# sous, absous, dissous, résolu

Tags: verbes, étymologie, origine-ou-raison, latin

Voici un paradigme qui présente des contradictions :

> - soudre | il sout | il solut | il a **sous** | solution
> - absoudre | il absout | il absolut | il a **absous / te** | absolution
> - dissoudre | il dissout | il dissolut | il a **dissous / te** | dissolution
> - résoudre | il résout | il résolut | il a **résolu / e** | résolution

Récemment j'ai entendu une locutrice du français langue seconde qui disait « il a dissous » et j'ai pensé que ce devrait être « dissolu », puis je me suis étonné lorsque j'ai consulté le conjugueur.

Par quel processus historique cette situation s'est-elle produite ?

À lire Wiktionnaire et les étymologies dans le TLF, je constate que :

- le participe passé en latin comportait la séquence *[-solu-](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/solutus#Forme_de_verbe)* (ce qui explique la forme nominale *-solution*)
- *[soudre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/soudre)*, étant désuet, n'est pas représenté
- *[absoudre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/absoudre)* est cité depuis au moins le Xe siècle, et depuis au moins le XIVe avec un participe passé comparable à *absous*
- *[dissoudre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/dissoudre)* est cité depuis au moins le XIIe, comportant pendant ce siècle et le suivant un participe passé comparable à *dissolu* : plus tard (XVIIe) « refait [en termes de conjugaison ?] d'après *absoudre* »
- *[résoudre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/r%C3%A9soudre)* est cité depuis au moins le XIIIe, premièrement avec le participe passé *résous* mais depuis le XIVe comparable à *résolu*

Ce dernier me semble encore trop tôt pour que ce soit sous l'influence normalisante du classicisme ou de l'Académie qu'on aurait emprunté *résolu* à la forme latine : et si j'ai bien entendu le commentaire sur *dissous*, cette normalisation a peut-être même opté pour l'autre sens.

Alors, comment ou pourquoi est-ce que *sous*, *absous*, *dissous* ont changé de forme tandis que *résolu* a gardé la forme originale ?

Answer (score 3):

On remarquera au passage que ni *absoudre* ni *dissoudre* n'ont de passé simple. (Et bien accessoirement, pas d'imparfait du subjonctif) alors que *résoudre* autorise ces conjugaisons... coïncidence ? Non évidemment mais... on pourra la traiter dans un autre sujet.

On va commencer par *Absoudre* puisque probablement le plus ancien, issu via une lente évolution phonétique, du latin parlé en Gaule dès le IV<sup>e</sup> siècle. Le DHLF le considère comme appartenant au *véritable fonds historique du français*.

En AF, il dispose d'un participe passé (*absolz, absolte*).

Comme il en va souvent ainsi, (*moldre->moudre, poldre->poudre*...) un *u* a *adouci* le *l* et on arrive au *absous / absoute*, qui nous est resté.

Contrairement donc à ce qui est affirmé dans l'OP, *absous* n'a pas changé de forme. Il a juste suivi la lente évolution phonétique qu'ont connu tous les mots venus du gallo-roman.

*Dissoudre* n'offre pas vraiment de quoi s'attarder. Plus tardif qu'absoudre on calque!

*Résoudre*... **idem!**

Idem! J'insiste! Et il a d'autant moins de raison de différer des précédents qu'il arrive dans notre langue en quasi-synonyme de *dissoudre*!

Participe passé : ***résous / résoute***. (*Brouillard résous en pluie* Ac.7)

Comm d'hab' on trouvera évidemment des grammairiens pour s'alpaguer, certains, des XVI<sup>e</sup>-XVII<sup>e</sup> préférant *résout / résoute*, d'autres refusant de lâcher *résous* mais refusant qu'il se fléchisse au féminin... Ah, Bhah! *grammatici certant* comme on dit entre nous... Bref! Pââsssons!

Vous m'direz... bon! soit! mais... et alors... et *résolu* dans tout ça ? Il existe bien quand même ce participe passé. Ce *résolu* qui, aux dires de l'OP aurait *gardé sa forme originale*... sa forme originale... de quoi ?

La réponse s'impose donc d'elle même : La forme originale du participe passé de... ?

D'un **homonyme** de *résoudre*. Apparu (au XIV<sup>e</sup> effectivement) avec le sens de *décider* (c'est bien à dire un tout autre sens que celui de *réduire*).

Il s'agit bien d'un authentique homonyme puisque alors que... l'autre dont il a été question plus haut est issu de l'AF, ce *résolu*-là est directement emprunté au latin classique *resolutus* (p.pas. de *resolvere*) . Une bien authentique re-création donc avec son chemin étymologique propre, son passé simple et n'ayant évidemment ni subi ni à subir l'évolution phonétique d'un long moyen-âge passé. Les linguistes parlent de *réemprunt*.

Absolument aucun changement de forme d'aucune sorte, **aucune contradiction** et pour aucun donc. Pour *résoudre*, les deux homonymes vivront leur vie en toute (relative<sup>1</sup>) indépendance très longtemps. On peut trouver des grammaires du XIX<sup>e</sup> et des dicos du début XX<sup>e</sup> rapportant la coexistence des deux participes avec la distinction de sens afférente.

L'alignement de *résous* sur *résolu*, n'est donc que (relativement) très récent. La fréquence d'emploi du second, le besoin de cohérence avec la conjugaison du passé simple (usurpé) auront raison du premier qui finira *désuet* dans le Grand Larousse de ca. 1980.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Il me semble au demeurant que *résous*, en tant que participe passé adjectivé était en usage à Québec de mon vivant. Mais... j'en sais ici par mieux placés que moi pour (con/in)firmer.</sub>

<sub>1 : Dans la mesure où le premier *résoudre* piquera quand même (sans aucune légitimité autre que le seul besoin) la conjugaison du passé simple propre au second... intrusion qui rendra, par là même, son propre participe passé intrus.</sub>

<sub>NDaCOSwt suite à interrogation de l'OP en commentaires : Quand on dit qu'il n'y a pas de passé-simple (ni imparfait du subjonctif) c'est seulement parce que l'on ne l'a jamais ou très peu lu/entendu employé. La raison de cela est très simple : **personne (ou très peu d'écrivains) n'en a ressenti le besoin.**</sub>
<sub>Dans toutes les langues vivantes, quand *blahblahwhatever* n'existe pas et qu'un écrivain en ressent le besoin, il le crée. Après, il est plus ou moins bien reçu par le public qui le comprend, l'accepte, le réutilise... ou pas! Il sera possiblement critiqué par certains grammairiens ou certaines Académies mais qui ne disposent d'aucun pouvoir pour l'interdire.</sub>
<sub>Cela étant donc affirmé que personne n'en a jamais eu besoin ne signifiant ni qu'il est interdit ni que personne n'en ressentira jamais le besoin, il est des règles très formelles relativement à la formation du passé simple et de l'imparfait du subjonctif. Au point que l'on peut tout à fait **prédire** (Avec les systèmes automatisés je dirais presque *calculer*) quelles ces conjugaisons seraient **si**, d'aventure, on en ressentait le besoin. D'où leur présence dans le wikitionnaire (en grisé) ou d'autres correcteurs orthographiques qui, pour les conjugaisons, fonctionnent en suivant des algorithmes en ne s'embarrassant que du minimum d'exceptions.</sub>

Comment: De manière générale, il vaut mieux aller directement au but que de faire du storytelling dans les réponses. De plus, n'hésite pas à ajouter des sources. "*absous n'a pas changé de forme. Il a juste suivi la lente évolution phonétique*" Ah bon ? D'où tiens-tu l'info ? "*Dissoudre n'offre pas vraiment de quoi s'attarder. Plus tardif qu'absoudre on calque!*" Comment ça, "pas de quoi s'attarder" ? En quoi est-il plus tardif qu'absoudre ?

Comment: This answer is plausible (to sum it up: *résoudre* followed the pattern but was re-borrowed as a separate lexical item with Latinate forms and later absorbed the natural AF paradigm), but I agree with Goat that I'd want a couple of sources to explore. Also, in those TLF etymologies I linked to, you can see this XIIe example for *dissoudre*: « li mollece de l'omme nos avoit dissoluz » ; unlike *absoudre*, the article is so light that I can't even find an explicit transition to *dissous*. Meanwhile, the different senses of *résoudre* in the TLF do grant some basis to your separate items account!

Comment: De plus, je suis curieux même si c'est une autre histoire comme tu le remarques : Ngrams, la note de WordReference qui [affirme](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/FRverbs.aspx?v=absoudre) qu'*absoudre* "is rarely used in the passé simple" et [de vieux livres](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zm5ysGvh74YC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=%22je+dissolus%22#v=onepage&q=%22je%20dissolus%22&f=false) semblent légitimer l'affirmation qu'on n'utilise pas cette forme : pourquoi donc apparatrait-elle dans les conjugueurs comme [celui-ci](http://bescherelle.com/conjugueur.php) ? D'où tire-t-on cette idée ?